# How to config Spring bean for prototype?

Tags: java, spring

I wrote it as a singleton before, there were no errors.
But I think I should make it instance per request.
And I have the code

```
<!--Dao configuration-->
<bean id="userDao" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean" scope="request">  
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="Dao.UserDao"></property>  
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"></property>  
</bean> 


package Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import Common.InitDataBases;
import Common.Controller.OutputStringController;
import Dao.UserDao;
import Model.User;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@Controller
@Scope("request") 
public class Hello extends OutputStringController{
    private UserDao uDao;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUser", produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody 
    public String dbTest(String username) {
        System.out.println(uDao.findByUsername(username).getUsername());
        return success("");
    }
    @Required 
    public void setuDao(UserDao uDao) {
        this.uDao = uDao;
    }

}
```

and it threw an exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'uDao' is required for bean 'hello'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:44)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod.createWithResolvedBean(HandlerMethod.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:323)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and I can't find a solution for it now.
I would like to make it like : Each http request will create a controller , a service,and a dao.
Help!

Comment: If the problem is not fix yet then can you please add the where User Dao class code here

Comment: thanks,I still don't understand dao config but I make the service and controller "prototype",I think it satisfy me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need @Scope("request")  this,the default is prototype in springmvc

Comment: how do yo know I am chinese my english baolu？

Comment: but I have a dao field,I need prototype and request

Comment: @Scope("prototype")

Comment: the same as org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'uDao' is required for bean 'hello'

Answer (score 0):

looking at the exception

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'uDao' is required for bean 'hello'

uDao is not configured to be injected in to the bean.

Try using

```
@Autowired
private UserDao uDao;
```

also make sure if component scan is enabled in the xml configuration.

Comment: I used to use this,and if the userDao is singleton,it's ok.but I writed it as "prototype" and it throw

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'Dao.UserDao' available:

Comment: can you check if there is a bean definition for UserDao class in the spring configuration xml file

Comment: the <bean id="userDao" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean" but the class is pointing to a MapperFactoryBean is this mapping right ??